# Why value isn't visible when getting it from this href?

Tags: javascript, php, html, backend, href

I want to send a value from a php file to another php file by using this:

```
$output .= '<a onclick="showDiv()" href="explore.php#chatArea?user_id='. $row['unique_id'] .'">
```

and when I try to get the user_id value with $_GET, it doesn't recognize the value. Instead, when I have something like this:

```
href="explore.php?user_id='.... (WITHOUT THE #chatArea)
```

it works fine. So how should I make it recognize with the id also?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because url part after `#` is not present in PHP. You should put it at the end of URL

```
$output .= '<a onclick="showDiv()" href="explore.php?user_id='. $row['unique_id'] .'#chatArea">
```

Comment: thaaaank you  a lot!! you saved me. It works fine, but the only problem is that I have to click twice on the user to see the value.. any idea why? If not, no problem, is still great that you made it work

Comment: @info_deniz No, can't help with that. Maybe some JS logic issues, but links in HTML works with single click

Answer (score 0):

Generally, one would use hash in the uri to link to an anchor. However, since the passing value is a GET query, it is not interpreted. You can simply omit the hash tag.